# Adding TWO events to an IF statement... Need help!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I have a script that works fine, but I need to add a second tag that changes background position at a different value.  I need to add  **$('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 -39px');** *in addition* to the existing script.

So now two tags change as a result of the if statement instead of one.  How would you do this?  Is there an AND?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#fastContact').formValidator({
scope : '#cform',
errorDiv : '#errorDiv2',
onError : function() {

if ($('#box_inputA input').hasClass('error-input')) {
$('#box_inputA , #box_inputR').css('background-position','0 -39px');
} else {
$('#box_inputA , #box_inputR').css('background-position','0 0');
}

if ($('#box_inputB input').hasClass('error-input')) {
$('#box_inputB , #box_inputR').css('background-position','0 -39px');
} else {
$('#box_inputB , #box_inputR').css('background-position','0 0');
}

if ($('#box_inputM textarea').hasClass('error-input')) {
$('#box_inputM').css('background-position','0 -84px');
$('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 -39px');

} else {
$('#box_inputM').css('background-position','0 0');
$('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 0');
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can add as many you like. Before you close out the if and go into the else you can issue anothe statement.

Comment: Uh... did you try just putting one statement after the other inside the `if`? Why else did you think the `{}` are required? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. My syntax may be off. I don't really know Javascript at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#fastContact').formValidator({
scope : '#cform',
errorDiv : '#errorDiv2',
onError : function() {
var error = false;
if ($('#box_inputA input').hasClass('error-input')) {
$('#box_inputA').css('background-position','0 -39px');
error = true;
} else {
$('#box_inputA').css('background-position','0 0');
}

if ($('#box_inputB input').hasClass('error-input')) {
$('#box_inputB').css('background-position','0 -39px');
error = true;
} else {
$('#box_inputB').css('background-position','0 0');
}

if ($('#box_inputM textarea').hasClass('error-input')) {
$('#box_inputM').css('background-position','0 -84px');
error = true;
} else {
$('#box_inputM').css('background-position','0 0');
}

if(error == true) {
   $('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 -39px');
}
else {
   $('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 0');
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Heh, you were faster :D Almost the same time :)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work correctly.  Try the validation with the contact form in the footer:  www.logicpkg.com with the message field.

Comment: @Erik: What's supposed to happen, exactly? I click "Send" on the empty form and all required fields turn red.

Comment: No just the name, email, and message.  the "required" rag is supposed remain red IF the message is complete but one of the other two fields are in error...... I'll add the whole script

Comment: Hmm, okay. So if I click Send when the form is empty, name, email, message, and 'required' all turn red. Then I filled in a message, hit Send, and message and 'required' turned blue while name and email stayed red. You want 'required' to remain red?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the condition statement.  If the message field is complete but the others are not, then the REQUIRED tag needs to remain red...

Comment: Do I need ad more conditions to the other two tags in the script?

Comment: @Erik: I updated my post. I won't swear to the syntax being right, but the idea basically is to record when an error occurred and modify box_inputR based on that just once at the end after all the other fields have been checked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you question you want this:

```
   if ($('#box_inputM textarea').hasClass('error-input')) {
       $('#box_inputM').css('background-position','0 -84px');
       $('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 -39px');
    } else {
       $('#box_inputM').css('background-position','0 0');
       $('#box_inputR').css('background-position','0 0');
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work correctly.  Try the validation with the contact form in the footer:  www.logicpkg.com with the message field.